# Deprecated gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with gradle 6.0?

Tags: react-native

I have done projects in React but not in React Native, When I tried to explore react native , I got this error , It has been 2 days and I still can't find the solution to it anywhere.

Please help me solve this issue

Comment: Could you please tun the app using Android Studio and share the log?

Comment: I'm using VSCode, But sure i'll do that